# Manipulate DateTimeFormField while clikcing on radio button

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I've to change `DateTimeFormField` date according ti given condition into radio button. For example, if I select **Yes**, I've to set `DateTimeFormField` value as DateTime.now(). For **N/A** `DateTimeFormField` will be empty. I'm using `setState` in Yes, N/A for changing the value. The value is changing but not showing into `DateTimeFormField`. I mean it's not refreshing. How can I refresh the `DateTimeFormField` value according to **Yes, N/A** selection?

```
DateTimeFormField(
  dateFormat: DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'),
  mode: DateTimeFieldPickerMode.date,
  initialValue: DateTime.parse(list[index].end!),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    isDense: true,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.w, vertical: 10.h),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
    errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.event_note),
  ),
  onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
    list[index].end= value.toString();
  },
)

Radio<String>(
value: list[index].yes!,
groupValue: "Y",
onChanged: (value) {
  setState(() {
    list[index].naFlag = "N";
    list[index].yes = "Y";
    list[index].yes = "Y";

    if(list[index].start== null) {
      list[index].start= DateTime.now().toString();
    }
    if(list[index].end== null) {
      list[index].end= DateTime.now().toString();
    }
  });
  list[index].yes = "Y";
  list[index].naFlag = "N";
},
activeColor: Colors.blue,
)
```

Comment: if you have a code snippet, that would help

Comment: William Terrill I've updated my question with snippet. Have a look.

Comment: I think that the onDateSelected needs a setState

Comment: it's not working. ui not updating.

Comment: can you paste more of your code? I am especially interested in your build method and how it is invoked. If you can do it on dartpad that would be even better. How is the onDateSelected triggered?

Comment: I've to reset ``DateTimeFormField`` value when user clicked on ``Yes/No``. For ``Yes`` if ``start and end date`` is empty then I've to set DateTime.now(), for ``No``  reset end as ``NULL``